# Complement of empty index vector is empty index vector

Tags: r, indexing

I am removing values from a vector by using - (minus sign)  in front of the index vector. Like this:

`scores <- scores[-indexes.to.delete]`

Sometimes `indexes.to.delete` vector is empty, that is N/A. So the `scores` vector should then remain unchanged. However, I am getting empty `scores` vector when `indexes.to.delete` is empty.

Example:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3);
y <- c(4, 5, 6);
indexes.to.delete <- which(y < x); # will return empty vector
y <- y[-indexes.to.delete]; # returns empty y vector, but I want y stay untouched
```

I could code an if statement checking whether `indexes.to.delete` is empty, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way?

Comment: You don't need to put in closing semi-colons in R.

Comment: I actually noticed that leaving semi-colons out did not produce errors. I guess it is a habit which I have to unlearn. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use;

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(4, 5, 6)
y[!y<x]
> y[!y<x]
[1] 4 5 6

x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(4, 1, 6)
> y[!y<x]
[1] 4 6
>
```

Comment: Basically ttmaccer is saying "You don't need to use which.  Why are you using which?"

Comment: I was using which because I had rather complicated selection condition.