# Subsetting vector: how to programatically pass negative index safely?

Tags: r, indexing

Given a vector, say `v = 1:10`, one can remove elements from `v` using negative indexing, e.g. `v[-1]`, `v[-length(v)]`, `v[-c(2,3)]`, to remove the first, last and 2nd/3rd element respectively.

I would like to split `v` by passing in a split index `n`, taking values 0 to `length(v)`. The code below:

```
v1 <- v[1:n]
v2 <- v[-c(1:n)]
```

works perfectly fine except for `n = 0`. Now I know that `1:n` is generally unsafe and should be replaced with `seq_len(n)`, however, the assignment `v2 <- v[-seq_len(0)]` produces an empty vector.

Is there way of doing this 'safely' using the bracket subsetting notation? Otherwise I know how to do it using head and tails:

```
v1 <- head(v, n)
v2 <- tail(v, length(v) - n)
```

Relevant other q/as:

[Complement of empty index vector is empty index vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915825/complement-of-empty-index-vector-is-empty-index-vector)

Comment: I am sure this is a dupe but can't seem to find the question/answer somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `if()` statement inside the brackets. For example, this will just return the whole vector if `n` is zero and remove the sequence `1:n` otherwise.

```
x <- 1:10

n <- 0
x[ if(n == 0) TRUE else -seq_len(n) ]  ## n == 0 is !n for the golfers
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

n <- 5
x[ if(n == 0) TRUE else -seq_len(n) ]
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: this is really neat but I guess I was hoping for something more readable for my six month future self, it also creates a side-effect `s` into the workspace.

Comment: `x[if(!length(s <- seq_len(n))) TRUE else -s]` as a potentially small simplification

Comment: @Alex - I took care of the side-effect issue.  And will add thelatemail's suggestion as well.

Comment: A way to evade defining s would be to do `x[if(n == 0) -(length(x) + 1) else seq_len(n)]`

Comment: great, thus the general solution is to use an if statement to construct the index. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
v = 1:10
n = 0; split(v, seq_along(v)/min(n,length(v)) <= 1)
#$`FALSE`
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

n = 1; split(v, seq_along(v)/min(n,length(v)) <= 1)
#$`FALSE`
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$`TRUE`
#[1] 1

n = 10; split(v, seq_along(v)/min(n,length(v)) <= 1)
#$`TRUE`
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

n = -10; split(v, seq_along(v)/min(n,length(v)) <= 1)
#$`TRUE`
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

n = 100; split(v, seq_along(v)/min(n,length(v)) <= 1)
#$`TRUE`
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Further simplified by [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615728/subsetting-vector-how-to-programatically-pass-negative-index-safely/42615940?noredirect=1#comment72361006_42615940) in comment

```
split(v, seq_along(v) > n)
```

Comment: Why not just `v[seq_along(v) > n]` ?

Comment: Good point on the split, I missed that in the question. `split(v, seq_along(v) > n)` then?

Comment: @RichScriven - it looks like it is added in the answer above now.