# Efficiently split matrix down its centre

Tags: r

Given the following matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(15),5,3)


           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812
[2,]  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432
[3,] -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406
[4,]  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999
[5,]  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309
```

I would like to supply a vector with the same number of rows as `x` with integer values between 1 and the number of columns of `x`, e.g.

```
split_vector = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
```

and apply the operation that 'splits the matrix `x` into three matrices', each of the same size as `x`. The first contains all columns in each row to the left of the corresponding index in `split_vector`, the second containing entries given by the indices in `split_vector`, and the third containing all other entries. For example, denote these matrices as `M1, M2, M3` respectively, then:

```
M2 <- matrix(rep(F, prod(dim(x))), ncol = ncol(x))
M2[cbind(seq_len(nrow(x)), split_vector)] <- T
M2[M2] <- x[M2] # very naughty coercion here
> M2
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.6264538  0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,]  0.0000000  0.4874291  0.0000000
[3,]  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.6212406
[4,]  1.5952808  0.0000000  0.0000000
[5,]  0.0000000 -0.3053884  0.0000000
```

Comment: I am interested in all these matrices but I haven't had the time to produce corresponding answers for `M1` and `M3`

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach to creating M2?

Comment: I do not know whether it is the most efficient way of doing it, besides, it would be nice to create all these matrices in one go using something similar to `split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create output matrix

```
out1 <- out2 <- out3 <- matrix(0, nrow(x), ncol(x))
```

Create indicators that meet each condition and use to add relevant values from x

```
id1 <- col(x) < v
out1[id1] <- x[id1]

id2 <- col(x) == v
out2[id2] <- x[id2]

id3 <- !(id2 + id1)
out3[id3] <- x[id3]
```

Output

```
> out1
           [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[2,]  0.1836433 0.0000000    0
[3,] -0.8356286 0.7383247    0
[4,]  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[5,]  0.3295078 0.0000000    0
> out2
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.6264538  0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,]  0.0000000  0.4874291  0.0000000
[3,]  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.6212406
[4,]  1.5952808  0.0000000  0.0000000
[5,]  0.0000000 -0.3053884  0.0000000
> out3
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]    0 -0.8204684  1.5117812
[2,]    0  0.0000000  0.3898432
[3,]    0  0.0000000  0.0000000
[4,]    0  0.5757814 -2.2146999
[5,]    0  0.0000000  1.1249309
```

Comment: this is very clever use of `col`.

Comment: @Alex, this is also the most efficient of the three approaches and should probably get the check mark :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615940/7128934).

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(15),5,3)
split_vector = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)

x = data.frame(cbind(x,split_vector)) #cbind x and split_vector so that 'apply' can be used on rows

M1 = function(v, n){
    extract = v[seq_along(v) < n]
    l = length(v) - length(extract)
    return(c(extract, rep(0, l)))
}

M2 = function(v, n){
    extract = v[seq_along(v) == n]
    l1 = n-1
    l2 = length(v) - n
    return(c(rep(0, l1), extract, rep(0, l2)))
}

M3 = function(v, n){
    extract = v[seq_along(v) > n]
    l = length(v) - length(extract)
    return(c(rep(0, l), extract))
}

t(apply(x, 1, function(a) M1(v = a[-length(a)], n = a[length(a)])))
#           [,1]      [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[2,]  0.1836433 0.0000000    0
#[3,] -0.8356286 0.7383247    0
#[4,]  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[5,]  0.3295078 0.0000000    0

t(apply(x, 1, function(a) M2(v = a[-length(a)], n = a[length(a)])))
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -0.6264538  0.0000000  0.0000000
#[2,]  0.0000000  0.4874291  0.0000000
#[3,]  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.6212406
#[4,]  1.5952808  0.0000000  0.0000000
#[5,]  0.0000000 -0.3053884  0.0000000

t(apply(x, 1, function(a) M3(v = a[-length(a)], n = a[length(a)])))
#     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,]    0 -0.8204684  1.5117812
#[2,]    0  0.0000000  0.3898432
#[3,]    0  0.0000000  0.0000000
#[4,]    0  0.5757814 -2.2146999
#[5,]    0  0.0000000  1.1249309
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not likely to find a readymade function for this, but you can try something like the following. Here, I've made use of `melt` from the "reshape2" package for converting a `list` to a `data.frame` (which I then convert to a `matrix` for matrix indexing).

```
myFun <- function(inmat, splitvec) {
  require(reshape2)
  M1 <- M2 <- M3 <- `dim<-`(rep(0, prod(dim(inmat))), dim(inmat))
  M1Val <- as.matrix(rev(melt(lapply(splitvec, function(x) (1:x)[-x]))))
  M2Val <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(inmat)), splitvec)
  M3Val <- as.matrix(rev(melt(lapply(splitvec, function(x) (x:ncol(inmat))[-1]))))
  list(M1 = {M1[M1Val] <- inmat[M1Val]; M1},
       M2 = {M2[M2Val] <- inmat[M2Val]; M2},
       M3 = {M3[M3Val] <- inmat[M3Val]; M3})
}
```

With your sample data, you get a list of 3 matrices, as follows:

```
myFun(x, split_vector)
## $M1
##            [,1]      [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
## [2,]  0.1836433 0.0000000    0
## [3,] -0.8356286 0.7383247    0
## [4,]  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
## [5,]  0.3295078 0.0000000    0
## 
## $M2
##            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
## [1,] -0.6264538  0.0000000  0.0000000
## [2,]  0.0000000  0.4874291  0.0000000
## [3,]  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.6212406
## [4,]  1.5952808  0.0000000  0.0000000
## [5,]  0.0000000 -0.3053884  0.0000000
## 
## $M3
##      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
## [1,]    0 -0.8204684  1.5117812
## [2,]    0  0.0000000  0.3898432
## [3,]    0  0.0000000  0.0000000
## [4,]    0  0.5757814 -2.2146999
## [5,]    0  0.0000000  1.1249309
##
```